# Setting Variable in other ViewController, having issues

Tags: ios

i want to set a variable in another viewcontroller, so that its there when i swap to it, here is the code:

CalendarMonthViewController.m

```
#import "ViewControllerInsert.h"
...

- (void) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate*)date{
    NSLog(@"Date Selected: %@",date);


    ViewControllerInsert *controller = [[ViewControllerInsert alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerInsert" bundle:nil];
    controller.dateSelected = date;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Date is valid here, when i breakpoint or NSLog

ViewControllerInsert.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerInsert : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDate *dateSelected;

@end
```

ViewControllerInsert.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    NSDate *ds = self.dateSelected;

    NSString *dss = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ds];

    NSLog(@"works %@",dss);
}
```

Prints NULL

Either i am initializing it incorrectly, or the obj goes off the heap. Which shouldnt happen with "Strong" right?

Comment: dateSelected should not be of strong type, it should be of assign type as you are assigning the value.

Comment: you need to convert date into string using dateformatter.

Comment: The first NSLog works just fine, and it converts it via stringWithFormat, and i am trying Assign now

Comment: You can use singleton or delegate. And it's duplicate. There are a lot of question with answers

Comment: try logging "self.dateSelected" in begining to find it has some value or not then you step down to next debugging.

Comment: How are you sing ViewControllerInsert.h view?Are you adding it as a subview ?

Comment: ya delegation would be fine

Comment: @JohnDOe bcoz first time you are passing nsdate in nslog. but second time you are passing string in nslog which is null. so it's printing null. use nsdateformatter and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you create an instance of a view controller, it does not mean that iOS will use that instance when it goes to show it. Why would it? How would iOS know to use your instance? It's not in the chain.

Instead, use a segue to go from one view controller to the next. In `prepareForSegue` on the originating view controller, you can reference the destination view controller like `[segue destinationViewController]`.

You can then set your custom properties on the destination view controller in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Agree, i also don't understand when it prints NULL, if view controller not presented and not forced to load it's view.

Answer (score 1):

So, calling of "viewDidLoad" method is not guarantied of its calling after calling setter of property "self.dateSelected".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your dateSelect property it's really NULL, you would have to see with a breakpoint in your code.

But I do notice that you are converting the NSDate to a NSString in a wrong way, and maybe that's why the NSLog are printing NULL.

To convert a NSDate to a NSString, you must user a NSDateFormatter. Try the code below:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];

NSString *dss = [formatter stringFromDate:self.dateSelected];
NSLog(@"works %@",dss);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should follow this step

```
 @interface ViewControllerInsert : UIViewController
  {
    NSDate *dateSelected;
   } 

 @property(nonatomic, assign) NSDate *dateSelected;



    @end


   and in .m file synthyse it like

     @synthesize dateSelected;
```

Comment: I guess author uses new xcode (if his code compiles), what means that it already not necessary to write this extra code. Also i thing that using strong is better then assign/weak in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Convert date like this.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ddmmyyyy"];

NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:self.dateSelected];

[formatter release];
```